# Rename "None" value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, null, rename

This is probably super simple but I just can not find the answer. I import data using GeoPandas from a shape file. Turn that into pandas `DataFrame`. I have a object field with three letter codes and `None` values for missing data. How do I change `None`'s to something like "vcv" in pandas? I tried this

```
sala.replace(None,"vcv")
```

got this error

```
   2400                                     "strings or regular expressions, you "
   2401                                     "passed a"
-> 2402                                     " {0!r}".format(type(regex).__name__))
   2403                 return self.replace(regex, value, inplace=inplace, limit=limit,
   2404                                     regex=True)

TypeError: 'regex' must be a string or a compiled regular expression or a list or dict of strings or regular expressions, you passed a 'bool'
```

Tried this

```
if sala['N10'] is None:
    sala['N10'] = 'Nul'
```

Does not change anything.

Comment: Do you mean the string 'None' or an empty string?

Comment: You can test for null values using `sala['N10'].isnull()`, so you can do sala.loc[sala['N10'].isnull(), 'N10'] = 'vcv'`should work

Comment: @Ajean: I think your answer, `sala.fillna(value='vcv')`, works. Why delete?

Comment: Yes it is "None". Ajean: I just need the column to change not everything in the table as you suggestion does. I have lots of numbers so vcv just will not do. I am merging on a text field and it will not work with the None.

Comment: does `sala.loc[sala['N10'] == 'None', 'N10'] = 'vcv'` work then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is just:

```
sala['N10'].replace('None', 'vcv', inplace=True)
```

that should work.

If they were true `NaN` values then calling `fillna` would've worked.

e.g.

```
sala['N10'].fillna(value='vcv', inplace = True)
```

also what I suggested in my comment:

```
sala.loc[sala['N10'].isnull(), 'N10'] = 'vcv'
```

Comment: OK small miss communication it is None as in no value but says "None" when you print out. But it is not text 'None'. Your solution sala.loc[sala['N10'].isnull(), 'N10'] = 'vcv' worked great. Thanks, Matthew